Soft Body Physics problems
Every time I use a cube and apply soft body physics to it the cube goes through the object  first and then deforms as if it has collided with the object 
It drops, goes through the object   and then  deforms. No  matter what I do or how many times i have subdivided the surface, used the solver settings , it always does it. As a matter of fact it does it with a uv sphere as well. Is it just my computer processor or is it  an  issue with one  of the settings.


I would either include your blend file via the blend-exchange upload (copy/paste the resulting text into an edit of your question) or include screenshot of your collision object Collision modifier settings.  There's not much information here -- including not enough of a screenshot of your SB parameters.  More info == quicker solution.



the cube (well, sphere in your file) has Soft Body and Rigid Body physics on it. This seems to confuse the collision detection. Probably because both physics have their own collision detections (Soft Body -> objects with Collision modifier/physics <=> Rigid Body -> other rigid objects). Remove the Rigid Body physics and it will work.

Thankyou , all solved
